# How force Intent not to re-create Activity instance while using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, android-activity

I'm navigating back in my back stack to the existing activity by using intent with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. Everything works as expected except of the fact that my activity is destroyed and re-created instead of being restarted.

Back stack:
A->B->C

How can I navigate from activity C to activity A without having it (A) re-created?

Answer (score 0):

If set in an Intent passed to `Context.startActivity()`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Thanks to [AGS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1569064/ags) for help in improving my answer.

Comment: it helped me a little - I have my original view not re-created but re-started and on the top of the stack but same time I have all my intermediate activities paused in back stack. What I need is to close all activities on the way back to the root (A). I can add finish() to calling activity (C) but it will not close activity B.